# angular factory dependency injection

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm trying to move some generic navigation formatting code from the controller into a factory.

Do I need to inject $scope into my factory? I've tried six ways from Sunday to inject $scope, but every method I've tried gives me errors.

Or do my stagesHeight, stagesWidth variables in the factory need scoping at all?

controller:

```
angular.module('sysomos.ads').
controller('LinkController', ['$scope', '$state', '$api', 'LinkFactory',
    function($scope, $state, $api, LinkFactory) {

     console.log(LinkFactory.make(['twitter', 'ad', 'view']));
    }
]);
```

factory:

```
angular.module('sysomos.ads').
factory('LinkFactory',  function(){
    return {
        make: function(arrSteps){

           $scope.stagesHeight = 30;// what scope does my logic need?
           $scope.stagesWidth = 145;
           // lots of intervening steps
           return arrSteps.join(",");// just return me the array for now

    };
}
```

]);

Comment: You don't attach or use `$scope` or `scope` inside a factory. Just go with plain JS variables.

Comment: Thanks. So do I var them, like plain-ol vanilla JS code?

Comment: Agreed, the factory doesn't even have a `$scope` in the way you're talking about it. If you REQUIRE some sort of attachment to the controller (which is what `$scope` really is), I would suggest finding a different way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
.factory('LinkFactory', function(){

    return {
        make: function(arrSteps){

            var stagesHeight = 30;// what scope does my logic need?
            var stagesWidth = 145;
            // lots of intervening steps

            return arrSteps.join(",");// just return me the array for now

};
}
```

Then call your service/factory from your ctrl like this:

```
$scope.foo.something = LinkFactory.make();
```

I hope this helps.