# angular factory to modify svg on page

Tags: angularjs, svg

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241753/angular-factory-dependency-injection), though they're only loosely related.

My factory is intended to place some svg boxes around some breadcrumb links.

My question is: is a factory the right way to do this? A factory should produce something and hand it back. Can I operate on an existing  element? Or should I rip the  element out of my HTML and have the whole HTML block generated in my factory, then return it to my controller?

Controller:

```
...
$scope.linkStages = [{'view': 'twitter'}, {'view': 'ad'}, {'view':'campaign'}];
...
        var coordinates = function(i) {
            i = Number(i);
            var x1 = i * stagesWidth + ',' + 0 + ' ';
            var x2 = i * stagesWidth + ',' + stagesHeight + ' ';
            var x3 = (i + 1) * stagesWidth + ',' + stagesHeight + ' ';
            var x4 = (i + 1) * stagesWidth + stagesHeight/2 + ',' + (stagesHeight/2) + ' ';
            var x5 = (i + 1) * stagesWidth + ',' + 0;
            return x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5;
        };

        /*
         * Calculate the position of the text inside a polygon
         * type 'y' will give the y coordinate
         * type not 'y' will given you the x coordinate
         * i is the position the polygon appears in the guide bar
         */
        var textCoord = function(i, type) {
            if (type === 'y') {
                return (stagesHeight/2) + 5;
            } else {
                return ((Number(i) + 0.5) * stagesWidth);
            }
        };
```

Factory:

```
// add fields to linkStage objs for visual display
for (var i in linkStages) {
     linkStages[i].title = '';
     linkStages[i].points = coordinates(i);
     linkStages[i].textX = textCoord(i, 'x');
     linkStages[i].textY = textCoord(i, 'y');
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="exportBar">
    <div class='svgContainer'>
        <svg sys-width='{{svgWidth}}' height='35' >
            <polygon ng-repeat="stage in linkStages.slice().reverse()" sys-points="{{stage.points}}" ng-class="exportView === stage.view ? 'selected': 'none'"/>
            <text ng-repeat="stage in linkStages" text-anchor="middle" sys-x="{{stage.textX}}" sys-y="{{stage.textY}}">{{stage.title | cut:false:12:'...'}}</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
</span>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('sysomos.ads').
directive('sysX', [
    function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('sysX', function(value) {
                attrs.$set('x', value);
            });
        };
    }
])
...
directive('sysPoints', [
    function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('sysPoints', function(value) {
                attrs.$set('points', value);
            });
        };
    }
]).
directive('sysWidth', [
    function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('sysWidth', function(value) {
                attrs.$set('width', value);
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: If I were you I would create a directive for that, I wouldn't use a service at all.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain your rationale? And where mine went awry?
Upon reflection, I see that a directive is intended to manipulate the DOM, which is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: sure, I will prepare an answer, but could you please share the rest of the html code? I mean, I can't see were the svg tag ends and I will suggest you to create a directive for that part, so I need to know where you are closing the tag, in order to know if I should transclude the directive or not. Thanks!

Comment: OP has been amended with more HTML.

Comment: There is a directive already. I'll add that to the OP as well. But the controller has about 100 lines of code dedicated just to manipulating the svg. (amended to OP). I'm just adding sample code to give you an idea. Not my intention to simply upload an entire module for a spoon-fed answer.